# Slick: comparing Rep[Option[Blob]] with Rep[Int]

Tags: scala, slick

I am using Slick to analyze a legacy MySQL database (with MyISAM engine). And I’m using implicit classes to navigate through entities, e.g. `user.logs` with this code:

```
implicit class UserNav(user: User) {
    def logs = Logs.filter(_.userId === user.id)
}
```

However, in this case the key is an INT but the foreign key is a BLOB. Using a MySQL client I can run `select userId * 1 from logs` to get an INT from the BLOB, and I can even join despite the different datatypes. But with Slick I get a compile errors for the code above.

```
error: Cannot perform option-mapped operation [ERROR]
with type: (Option[java.sql.Blob], Int) => R [ERROR]   
for base type:(java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Blob) => Boolean

error: ambiguous implicit values:
both value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Boolean]]]
and value BooleanCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean]
match expected type slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you convert the BLOB to an `Int`?

Comment: @bob I am not sure what you mean. However, I do am not allowed to alter the database. It’s also still in use (both read and write).

Comment: I'm saying that you know that you can't use a `BLOB`, so you will have to convert the `BLOB` to an `Int` so that Slick can use it. What happens when you do?

Comment: @bob The database is as it is. I am not allowed to change the datatype of that column. And in Scala I have no BLOB but Rep[Option[Blob]] -- no idea how to convert that to something that has to do with INT.

Comment: Change the expression in your filter to do the conversion. If `Logs` has a BLOB `userId`, then convert it to `Int` before doing the comparison. If you have to make the navigation class explicit, then so be it.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this makes no sense. `Log.userId` is not data, it's not a `BLOB` but a `slick.lifted.Rep`, which is for creating queries.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out by trying, just pretending the column has a different data type works.

So besides the original `val` in class `Log` (which extends `Table[LogRow]`)

```
val userId: Rep[Option[java.sql.Blob]] = column[Option[java.sql.Blob]]("userId", O.Default(None))
```

I added

```
val userId_asInt: Rep[Option[Int]] = column[Option[Int]]("userId", O.Default(None))
```

and changed the navigation `def` to

```
def logs = Logs.filter(_.userId_asInt === user.id)
```

This did the trick – at least with MySQL/MyISAM (no idea if this works with other engines or even other DBMS).

Instead I could also have replaced the data type in original `val userId`, but then I would also have to change that data type all over the place like in `Log.*` and `Log.?` ...